# Installation and download

Tags: system-installation

i have downloaded the Ubuntu system, but, it will not open, i have used a bittorrent, just a straight download, every way imaginable. Burned it to a disk, even tried a flash drive, no go, it will not, open and run, so, whats the secret, ok? Oh, and yes, that was the 14.4 distro

Comment: You actually burned it right? You didn't just copy the ISO to the disc? And what do you mean by "run?" Did you try to boot from it? Because that's what you need to do.

Comment: Sounds like you just copyed the file to flash drive as @Zacharee1 said. You need to actually make the boot here us a guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the ISO to the flash is not the way of boot. 
You want to create your flash as bootable device. Use the [Linux USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/)  for create bootable device. 
Then restart the computer with the flash for boot.